# Why is the UIEvent a different object in touchesBegan and touchesMoved?

Tags: iphone, touches

In the example project [aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html) application delegate the code indicates (and I've read elsewhere) that the touch event object passed to touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded will be the same object while it is still a single set of user actions, such as touching and moving a finger.  When I override UIScrollView and implement these methods, the events that I get back are different objects.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the `UIEvent` is reused when delivering touch events for one gesture. From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006780-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1):

> A UIEvent object representing a touch
>   event is persistent throughout a
>   multi-touch sequence; UIKit reuses the
>   same UIEvent instance for every event
>   delivered to the application. You
>   should never retain an event object or
>   any object returned from an event
>   object. If you need to keep
>   information from an event around from
>   one phase to another, you should copy
>   that information from the UITouch or
>   UIEvent object.

I presume the difference in behavior for your case results from the special event handling done by `UIScrollView`. Scroll views delay event delivery because they need to detect a scrolling intent by the user (swipe gestures). So they have to have a way of keeping UIEvents around—probably copying them to make sure they retain their original state. This might be the reason you see different objects.

Note that all of the above is only guessing.

Comment: What's the difference between `touchs` and `event.allTouches` in `touchesBegan` function?

Comment: @Bagusflyer `allTouches` returns all currently present touches while the passed argument only contains the touches relevant for this event.

Answer (score 3):

The `UITouch` objects will be the same, but they are packaged in a new event.

Comment: Surely aurioTouch isn't in error?  Did the behavior change, or am I misreading how the example app delegate works?  See the usage of pinchEvent.